how to draw a curve inside a cone
I want to draw a slight bended curve inside a cone like the following picture attached but my curve is outside this cone if i write "left bend" or "right bend". Is there some better way to draw bended curve inside this cone ??
Here is my code
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0)[thick,blue] circle(2 cm and 0.5cm);
        \draw[thick,blue] (-2,0)--(2,-4);
        \draw[thick,blue] (2,0)--(-2,-4);
        \draw(0,-4)[thick,blue] circle(2cm and 0.5cm);
        \filldraw[blue](0,-2) circle (2 pt);
        \draw[->,thick,red](0,-2)--(1,-1);
        \draw[->,thick,red] (0,-2)--node[midway,above]{null} (-1,-1);
        \draw[thick,green] (0,-4) to [bend left] node[midway,below]{timelike} (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code to a minimal working example (MWE).

A simple manual solution would be to set the x coordinates of the start and end point of your curved line to .6.

Look up to[in=,out=] to replace -- . By specifying input and output angles (0deg = east = to the right, cc-wise) you get more control. Consider drawing two curves from "Present", one up, one down.
